# Wrong WKWebView content scale when printing

Tags: swift, macos, wkwebview, appkit

I am using `WKWebView` to export data from my macOS app. I'm using CSS and `page-break-after: always;` to create pagination.

This works fine on most systems, but on some Macs, resulting `WKWebView` contents are scaled up about 5% — from `507px` to `536px`. This causes my CSS-driven pagination to run over page boundaries, resulting in orphaned pages.

I'm creating the web view programmatically, so the user can't have scaled it by mistake.  `NSPrintInfo` is also forced to use specific margins, and if those don't fit the `.imageablePageBounds`, the difference is taken into account. (This part is not in this sample code, though.)

```swift
func makeWebview(html:String) {
    webview = WKWebView()
    webview?.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
}

func exportToPDF (url: NSURL) {
    let printInfo = NSPrintInfo.shared
    printInfo.dictionary().addEntries(from: [
        NSPrintInfo.AttributeKey.jobDisposition: NSPrintInfo.JobDisposition.save,
        NSPrintInfo.AttributeKey.jobSavingURL: url
    ])
    
    // Set margins
    printInfo.topMargin = 12.5
    printInfo.leftMargin = 12.5
    printInfo.rightMargin = 12.5
    printInfo.bottomMargin = 12.5

    var offset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    let referenceMargin = 12.5
    let imageableOrigin = CGSize(width: printInfo.imageablePageBounds.origin.x, height: printInfo.imageablePageBounds.origin.y)
    
    if (imageableOrigin.width - referenceMargin > 0) {
        offset.width = imageableOrigin.width - referenceMargin
    }
    if (imageableOrigin.height - referenceMargin > 0) {
        offset.height = imageableOrigin.height - referenceMargin
    }
    
    printInfo.topMargin = printInfo.topMargin - offset.height;
    printInfo.leftMargin = printInfo.topMargin - offset.width;
    
    let printOperation = webview?.printOperation(with: printInfo)
    printOperation?.showsPrintPanel = false
    printOperation?.showsProgressPanel = true

    printOperation.view.frame = NSMakeRect(0,0, printInfo.paperSize.width, printInfo.paperSize.height)
    
    printOperation?.runModal(for: self.window, delegate: self, didRun: #selector(printOperationDidRun), contextInfo: nil)
}
```

My CSS also uses `cm` and `pt` sizes, which makes this issue even weirder. Again, this only happens on select systems, so I can't reproduce it myself.

```css
body {
    width: calc(21cm - 88pt); /* Accounts for printer margins */ 
    font-size: 12pt;
}
```

For some users, the results are very off, including previously set margins.

[image: faulty margins]

The faulty scaling **must** happen inside the web view, because as the pages flow over, page breaks still happen after correct elements. I know that `WKWebView` will scale contents to fit, causing the page to shrink, if content width exceeds printable width, but I haven't seen the opposite.

I'm wondering if there is a system-wide setting for web view contents scale, which could affect `WKWebView`?

Any hints or ideas are welcome.

**Update:** The issue happens when the user has no printers installed on their system. For some reason, `NSPrintInfo` has much smaller `imageablePageBounds` without a physical printer, and print operation also then scales up the contents.

This thread revolves around the same issue, with no apparent workaround:
[Cocoa printing with Swift: "Any" printer setup has irregular margins/page size, any workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59691305/cocoa-printing-with-swift-any-printer-setup-has-irregular-margins-page-size)

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: Simplified code is now there.

Comment: Do you set `webview.fame`, `printOperation.view?.frame` and/or the paper size somewhere?

Comment: Yes, it happened in another function, but I've added it to the code now.

Comment: Do all users use the same printer and paper size?

Comment: For now, those who experience issue, have used A4, though my app supports US Letter too. Although now that I've gathered more info, what's common for (most of) the users experiencing the issue, is that they don't have a physical printer installed.

Comment: Update: The issue is actually very much related to not having a printer installed. The shared `NSPrintInfo` will have much smaller `imageablePageBounds`. For some reason, page contents are also upscaled.